# How does one upgrade Riak, if it was initially downloaded from source?

Tags: riak

Riak has great documentation on how to upgrade Riak if it was initially installed via a package ( http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/cookbooks/Rolling-Upgrades/ ).  But how do you upgrade Riak if you originally downloaded/installed it from source?

The current version of Riak I'm using is 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same except in step 3 instead of

```
sudo dpkg -i <riak_package_name>.deb
```

you just download the tarball with new version and install it as you did first time.

But frankly speaking in 99% cases it's easier to do it via packages. I believe you can upgrade to packaged version from manually installed one by following their rolling update instructions precisely.